# Why the Focus widget mergeing the Accessibility focus in Flutter? (Focus works like MergeSemantics)

Tags: flutter

I recognised this weird behaviour that Focus widget mergeing RichText and TextFormField together semantically. It's like focus widget working as the MergeSemantics widget. As I interpreted the documentation there is NO connection between the Focus tree and Semantics Tree.

Why is it working like MergeSemantics?

```
Focus(
focusNode: _nameFocusScopeNode,
child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                 children: [ RichText(
                 textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context),
                 text: const TextSpan(
                 text: "Name",
                 semanticsLabel: "Name mandantory field",
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, ),
                 children: <TextSpan>[],),),
           const SizedBox(height: 24),
           TextFormField(controller: _nameTextController, enabled: _inputFieldsEnabled,autovalidateMode: _autoValidate ? AutovalidateMode.always : AutovalidateMode.disabled, textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words, focusNode: _nameFocus)
```

Wrapping with Focus works like MergeSemantics

[image]

Without Focus works as expected.

[image]

Flutter version : (Channel stable, 2.10.4)

Answer (score 0):

Focus class has an **includeSemantics** property which is set to true by default.

To avoid the behavoiur presented above set this property to False.

[Flutter documentation: includeSemantics property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus/includeSemantics.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).